# Using wrapper class in Visual force Page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to use the below wrapper class in VF page as this class should return me record from Child Account and Address objects. However, I am unable to get it right. Please find the class below.

Please note - the condition `WHERE Child_Account__c ='0017E00000FZqdVQAT'` is used only for debugging purpose and I am expecting the list to return multiple rows.

In VF I'm trying to use :

```
<apex:repeat value="{!WrapperList}"  var="xx" >
```

But VF is showing error Unknown property ....WrapperList.

```
public without sharing class AffiliationWrapperClass {
    public List < AffiliationWrapper > WrapperList {get;set;}
    List < Child_Account__c > cAcList = new List < Child_Account__c > ();
    Set < Id > pAcId = new Set < Id > ();
    public AffiliationWrapperClass() {
        for (Child_Account__c cAc: [SELECT Name, OK_Role__c, Parent_Account__c, Work_Status_AGN__c,
                Parent_Account_vod__r.Beds__c, Parent_Account_vod__r.Name,
                Child_Account__c, Copy_Address__c, Network_Primary__c
                FROM Child_Account__c
                WHERE Child_Account__c = '0017E00000FZqdVQAT'
            ]) // filter with child acc
        {
            cAcList.add(cAc);
            pAcId.add(cAc.Parent_Account__c);
        }
        Map < Id, Address__c > addrMap = new Map < Id, Address__c > ([select Account__c, Name from Address__c
            WHERE Account__c IN: pAcId
        ]); // filter with child's parent acc
        for (Child_Account__c ca: cAcList) {
            WrapperList.add(New AffiliationWrapper(ca, addrMap.get(ca.Parent_Account__c)));
        }
    }
    Public Class AffiliationWrapper {
        Child_Account__c accObj;
        String fullAddress;
        Public AffiliationWrapper(Child_Account__c accRec, Address__c addr) {
            accObj = accRec;
            fullAddress = addr.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add your vf page code as well. have you added AffiliationWrapperClass  as controller or extension?

Comment: No, I'm calling AffiliationWrapperClass  from my VF page's controller class.

Answer (score 2):

Your VF page reference needs to look like:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!someCtrlGetterOfTypeAffiliationWrapperClass.WrapperList}"  var="xx" >
```

That is, the page can only see as the top level expression in the `{!...}` getters in the controller (or any super classes of the controller). Those getters can in turn be of types that reference objects in other classes.

Answer (score 0):

WrapperList instance variable should have a getter method, try to initialize list in getter method rather than in constructor.

```
public class WrapperController {

    // Wrapper inner class
    List<DisplayAccountContacts> accounts;

    /**
    * Getter method to set records
    * */
    public List<DisplayAccountContacts> getAccounts(){
        if(accounts == null){
            accounts = new List<DisplayAccountContacts>();
            for(Account acc : [Select Id, Name, (Select Id, FirstName from Contacts) from Account]){
                accounts.add(new DisplayAccountContacts(acc));
            }
        }
        return accounts;
    }

    /**
    * Inner Wrapper class
    * */
    public class DisplayAccountContacts {
        private Account account;
        private DisplayAccountContacts(Account account){
            this.account = account;
        }
        public String name{
            get {return account.Name;}
        }
        public String contactName{
            get{
                if(account.contacts.size() > 0){
                    return account.contacts[0].FirstName;
                }else{
                    return 'No Contacts';
                }    
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

VisualForce page

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="acc">
```

Comment: It already does have a getter... `public List < AffiliationWrapper > WrapperList {get;set;}`

Answer (score 0):

Child_Account__c accObj and  String fullAddress  inside the wrapper class- was Private. and that was causing the issue as variables was not accssibles outside in the page .Else the code is working fine.